# Found a bug in the URL rewrite module that we can't fix. Need suggestions for outbound URL rewriting

Tags: rewrite, asp.net, .net

I'm looking for some high-level options for coding around a bug I discovered in the URL rewrite module for outbound URL's. We're at an impasse with Microsoft because they need a full crash dump, which contains confidential client data that we're legally bound from sharing with them. They can't debug on our servers because the symbol files for URL rewrite are apparently guarded.

I'm on the infrastructure side, so my familiarity with .Net is tangential. I'm aware that global.asax can do some rewriting, but does that apply to outbound URL's as well?

Can we do it in code?

Any other good options?

---

---

**Details about the bug find, for those who are curious**

We were seeing periodic crashes in our production environment that didn't happen in any other environments. Although we have dev traffic in our dev environment, user traffic in our beta environment, and a series of tests, nothing was hitting the right conditions. The event logs were capturing the crashes with the exception code `0xc0000374`, which points to heap corruption.

At the time, I wasn't too familiar with debugging heap corruption, so I set up [ProcDump](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump) as a [post-mortem debugger](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/enabling-postmortem-debugging), thinking that a crash dump would provide more information. The crash dumps we collected all had different stack traces and it all seemed like irrelevant information, sometimes pointing to our app, sometimes the .Net runtime.

I learned that the problem with debugging heap corruption is that the thread that *detects* corruption will often be different than the thread that *causes* corruption. Regardless of which thread detections corruption, the detection basically never occurs at the same instruction that causes corruption. So, basically, your crash dump would need to capture a moment in the past.

Enter, [PageHeap](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/gflags-and-pageheap). PageHeap is a utility that is enabled on a per process basis and essentially buffers all heap allocations with an unreadable/unwritable page in the region above and below each heap object. Any operation that reads or writes outside its memory bounds immediately causes an exception `0xC0000005` to be thrown, which is an unauthorized/illegal memory access violation, which is exactly what causes heap corruption.

With PageHeap enabled and our post-mortem debugger configured, we were able to capture a series of crash dumps. Unlike the previous crash dumps, every single crash dump had the exact same stack trace. The offending instruction in decompiled code that threw the exception was a `mul mov` instruction *in the URL rewrite module DLL*, which moves memory repeatedly, a number of operations determined by the value in the `esx` register. This fits with the behavior we are seeing of writing out of bounds.

PageHeap is surprisingly not a terrible load on the system. Our servers run around 30GB and this pushed them up to 38GB.

After sending the mini crash dump (which is only stack information) Microsoft confirmed the findings. They originally thought this was a known issue of interoperability between URL compression and URL rewrite, but URL compression is disabled, so this doesn't apply.

---

Thanks for any advice, and I hope you enjoyed my saga :)